# Processing: Would it be possible to use Processing language and render graphics in another GUI toolkits such as wxWidgets or Qt?

Tags: user-interface, processing, toolkit

I'd like to use Processing as graphics engine but make it work inside a wxWidgets or Qt GUI application. Is this possible and are there any references?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Processing is built on Java, you can use the following Qt-Java binding for your project. http://sourceforge.net/projects/qtjava/

I am not sure how up to date that package is though since I've read that it was being deprecated (even though the date says April 9, 2013).

As per the comment on the above page, there is another project known as Qt-Jambi which does basically the same thing: http://qt-project.org/wiki/Qt_Jambi

Here's a *really* outdated Java binding for wxWidgets http://wx4j.sourceforge.net/.

As a side note, Processing has its own GUI libraries with ControlP5 being my favorite. You can find it here: http://www.sojamo.de/libraries/controlP5/

Comment: Thanks nickecarlo. Would it be possible to use ControlIP5 to build a "multi-track" scheme to show a few scenes under the same GUI? Something like an audio editor would do. I checked out a few examples on ControlIP5 site but they all look more like video games where there is always just one active scene.

Comment: @kakyo Not sure what you mean by "multi-track", if you can provide a visual example I can look into it. Processing is mostly used as a tool by visual artists and for data visualizations. ControlP5 deals with those needs needs very well. Again, not sure what you mean.

Comment: http://www.vstplanet.com/Other_tools_photos/Full%20view/audacity.jpg This is an example. As you can see, several horizontal "tracks" showing audio waveforms are laid out vertically. I was wondering if controlP5 can do the same. Strange I cannot put @you in the front.

Comment: @kakyo Check this http://frontiernerds.com/brain-hack project out and scroll down to number "8 visualize". It doesn't look exactly like the audacity screen shots you sent me but I'm sure you can rearrange things. If you follow the "Download the code" link you can get the code for Processing and see how they've set it up. Its done in ControlP5 so that would help you wrap your head around it too.

Comment: Thanks a lot nick! That seems what I wanted.